# Stored Procedures SQL Count

Tags: mysql

Have created a stored procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER $
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS horse_sp$
CREATE PROCEDURE horse_sp(records INT(1))
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Horse
  WHERE records=horseid
  ORDER BY horseid
END$
```

Delimiter ;

That creates the procedure fine. Now how can I add a count function into this procedure, so that i'm able to return the number of records in the HORSE table using this procedure? And yes i've googled and browsed on here but can't work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Change it to `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: So I'd write it as:

Select Count(*) FROM Horse? 

if it's that simple i'm embarrassed lol.

Comment: Yeah. Procedures are no different in a procedure than when used normally.

Comment: And also. How do I run this stored procedure now that it's created, So I can get the results from the count?

This textbook i've got says EXEC horse_sp, but it doesn't work?

Comment: It should be `CALL horse_sp`.

Comment: Hmm.

For some reason when I did that, I get the error 1318: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE horsedb.horse_sp, expected 1 got 0

Comment: It expects the `records` argument, to select a specific `horseid`. Get rid of that if you want to count all horses.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions.

So from the CREATE PROCEDURE horse_sp, part, remove everything after that, so the (records INT(1)) ? 

Because when I do that, I then get an error when I try to create the procedure like that. Just really not sure how to write it.

Comment: I wonder, Is this procedure really working? look at the where clause `WHERE records=horseid` ? should it not be like `WHERE  horseid = records`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE horse_count()
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Horse
END$
```

Then you can use

```
CALL horse_count;
```